# Prove the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{H_t}{t}dt=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

By numerical results it follows that:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{H_t}{t}dt=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}=1.25774688694436963$$

Here $H_t$ is the [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which is the generalization of harmonic sum and has an integral representation:

$$H_t=\int_0^1 \frac{1-y^t}{1-y}~dy$$

---

If anyone has doubts about convergence, [we have](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BHarmonicNumber%5Bt%5D%2Ft,t-%3E0%5D):

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{H_t}{t} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Which would be another nice thing to prove, although I'm sure this proof is not hard to find.

---

It is also interesting that the related integral gives Euler-Mascheroni constant:

$$\int_0^1 H_t dt=\gamma$$

Comment: Wait a minute, your integral doesn't converge.

Comment: @abnry, Mahtematica computes it no problem $$\text{NIntegrate}\left[\frac{H_t}{t},\{t,0,1\}\right]$$

Comment: @abnry, Wolfram Alpha does too: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BHarmonicNumber%5Bt%5D%2Ft,%7Bt,0,1%7D%5D

Comment: whoops, my bad, I thought your $H_t$ was constant.

Comment: To prove the second part see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4655283/proving-that-lim-x-rightarrow0-frach-xx-frac-pi26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We apply 
$$
\frac{1-y^t}{1-y} = (1-y^t)(1+y+y^2+ \ldots)=(1-y^t)+y(1-y^t) +y^2(1-y^t)+\ldots
$$
Each term gives after $y$-integration, 
$$
\frac t{t+1} + \frac{t}{2(t+2)}+ \frac t{3(t+3)} + \ldots
$$
Then we divide these by $t$, 
$$
\frac 1{t+1} + \frac{1}{2(t+2)}+ \frac 1{3(t+3)} + \ldots
$$
Taking integral with $t$ variable, we have the result.

Any interchange of integral and summation can be justified by Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: That's nice and clear, thank you. If you want, look at my profile for more integrals equal to this series

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. By the way, your limit $\pi^2/6$ also can be proved from my solution.

Answer (score 4):

> **Solution to the first part of this question was provided by @i707107.**

---

For the second part, note that if we use the integral representation $H(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{1-y^t}{1-y}\,dy$, then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{H(t)}{t}&=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_0^1 \frac{1-y^t}{1-y}\,dy}{t}\\\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0}  \int_0^1 \frac{y^t \log(y)}{1-y}\,dy\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(y)}{1-y}\,dy\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-y)}{y}\,dy\\\\
&=\text{Li}_2(1)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

For the third part, we note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 H(t)\,dt&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1-y^t}{1-y}\,dy\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (y^n-y^{n+t})\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1+t}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\log(n+2)+\log(n+1)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{n}-\log(n+1)+\log(n)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n -\log(N+1)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n -\log(N)\right)\\\\
&=\gamma
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: (+1) very nice answer.

Comment: @Mittens Thank you.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>
> - $\ds{
>   \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + \mu}\pars{k + \nu}} =
>   {\Psi\pars{\mu} - \Psi\pars{\nu} \over \mu - \nu}\,,\qquad
>   \pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}}$.
> - $\ds{H_{z} = \Psi\pars{z + 1} - \Psi\pars{1}}$.

---

1. \begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{H_{t} \over t}\,\dd t} & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\Psi\pars{t + 1} - \Psi\pars{1} \over t}\,\dd t\qquad\qquad
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + t + 1}}\,\dd t =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k + 1}\,\ln\pars{k + 2 \over k + 1} =
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k}\,\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over k}}}
\end{align}

---

2. \begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\lim_{t \to 0}{H_{t} \over t}} & =
\lim_{t \to 0}{\Psi\pars{t + 1} - \Psi\pars{1} \over t} =
\lim_{t \to 0}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + t + 1}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}} =
\color{#f00}{\pi^{2} \over 6}
\end{align}